# How to store the data from the servlet to the Grid in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

I have a Servlet where i have two fields username and password that is coming from database and now i want to view the data in a grid in ExtJs i dont know what to do..

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


    try {
        String Username=request.getParameter("username");/* i want to show these two data to the grid 
        String Password=request.getParameter("password");*/

        JSONObject JSONobj=new JSONObject(); //this is json Object

        JSONArray json=new JSONArray();//this is json array
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

        obj.put("username",UserVO.getUsername());
        obj.put("password",UserVO.getPassword());

        json.add(obj);

        JSONobj.put("employee", json);
        response.sendRedirect("data-retrive.html");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception"+e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending response in `JSON` format from server. To read and to display, this response in ExtJS, you have to use `Ext.data.Model, Ext.data.reader.Reader, Ext.data.JsonStore, Ext.grid.Panel`.

You can find more details about `Ext.grid.Panel` on following link -

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

Also, take a look at [ExtJS Grid examples](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example)

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

        obj.put("username",UserVO.getUsername());
        obj.put("password",UserVO.getPassword());

        json.add(obj);
//obj object holds the data comes from database i want to call this object/data in my grid

Comment: var store=new Ext.data.JsonStore({
     
       url:'LoginServlet',
       fields:[
         
         'username','password'
     ]
     
     
  });

    store.load();

    var grid=new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        
        store:store,
        columns:[
            
            {header:'username',width:100,dataIndex:'username'},
            {header:'password',width:100,dataIndex:'password'}
            
        
    
        ],
        height:250,
        width:500      
        
    }); // i am doing these

Comment: url is a servlet that is LoginServlet

Comment: ok...so is your code working now or there is still an issue in it?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined  //its saying

Comment: may i have your email id then i will send the total code to you i have to do it plz

Comment: jeet.chatterjee.88@gmail.com //this is my mail id plz send a mail so that i can contact u @ Avinash T